# ExtJS Repositioning/resizing toolbar on window resize

Tags: extjs, resize, toolbar

I have a toolbar inside a simple container. They get rendered on a window's div. When I resize the window the toolbar remains stationary. If the window gets smaller the toolbar starts disappearing (overflowing outside). If the window gets bigger the toolbar stays in its position instead of trying to remain to the far right where it started. I've tried the resize and enable overflow configs but nothing seems to work. I'm thinking that its positioning through the div might be the problem but I'm not sure how to test or fix that. Any ideas?

Some sample code:

```
var toolbar = Ext.create('MyToolbar');
var toolbarContainer = Ext.create('widget.contaienr', {renderTo: 'myDiv', items: [toolbar]});
.
.
.
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this function in the EXtJs docs

```
onWindowResize( fn, scope, [options] )
```

Adds a listener to be notified when the browser window is resized and provides resize event buffering (100 milliseconds), passes new viewport width and height to handlers.

Example code looks like the below(I guess you have to write it in your afterRender .(You have to add this event and then fire it.))
Adding the event in the init component looks like below

```
this.addEvents('setInboxTileSource');
```

Firing the event in the afterRender looks like below

```
Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(function (w, h) {
    this.fireEvent('BROWSER_WINDOW_RESIZE')
}, this, {buffer: 150});
```

You have to listen the event and set your width and height for your toolbar.

```
listeners: {
     BROWSER_WINDOW_RESIZE: this.handleResize,
     scope: this
}

handleResize:function(){   
    this.setHeight(Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height - 270);
    this.setWidth(Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width- 100);
}
```

Hope this helps you...

Answer (score 0):

Toolbars should not be configured that way. If you have a window, it should be configured this way:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
     title:'some title'
    ,width:400
    ,height:300
    ,tbar:[{
        // here come toolbar items
    }]
});
```

For more examples see http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/menu/menus.html and other toolbar examples.

Comment: In our case we are opening a new jsp window that displays a PDF document. Over that we want JUST the toolbar that acts on the document. We cannot use window for now (we are in a period of migrating our program from Java2EE+JSF to ExtJS so we can't do everything with Ext yet) so I have to find a way to make the toolbar change size and position according to the browser window. I cannot use the tbar configuration and I am forced to use a container and a div to position it correctly.